# which structure I should use for this matlab arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I'm starting to develop a project which uses multi-dimensional arrays very often.
my arrays are mostly  2 , 3 dimensional or so.
As a 2D array sample consider 'A', I may have 2 or more 1D arrays in a cell.

sth like

```
A=[1, [78,9] [10,65], 9;
   2 ,       3 ,      6;
   7 ,      [9,1] , [91,41,96][10,-1]]
```

As you saw in 'A(1,2)' there are two 1D arrays.
I don't know which structure I should use to achieve such thing.
moreover I want to be able to have access to all those 1D arrays.

please share your knowledge with me.

Comment: Assuming that those numbers and sub-arrays have a meaning, I'd put them in structure and give them somewhat meaningful names...

Answer (score 3):

try using `cell` or `struct` i would recommend `cell`.

E.g. preinitialize `A1`:

```
A1=cell(3,3)
```

(that would be a 3x3 cell array/matrix). Then you can adress elements with curly brackets ({}). E.g.:

```
A1{1,1}= 1;
A1(1,1)={1};
```

both work. You can also define many cells in one line. E.g:

```
A1(2,:) = {2,3,6};
```

For the cases with multiarray entries use another cell structure:

```
B= {[78,9], [10,65]};
A1(1,2) = {B};
```

and so on. Pay attention to use curly brackets around `B` (or the coordinate in `A1`)! Otherwise he would try to merge the cells from `B` in `A1` but that won't do any good because `B` is a 1x2 cell and you want to give it as argument to one cell in `A1`.

If you want to return the value inside a cell you have to use curly brackets again:

```
 A1{1,1}
```

would return 1.

Comment: I'd prefer `A1{1,2} = B` over `A1(1,2) = {B}`. Avoids the intermediate creation of the trivial 1x1 cell array.

Comment: @sebastian could you elaborate that a bit? I haven't really gotten the difference between the two notations, I am selflearning matlab rightnow.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with such a structure. You could use cell arrays for each 1d array entry, and create a matrix of such cell arrays:

```
a = {1, 2};
b = {-1, 4, 6};
M = [a b];
```

Alternatively, you can define a sparse 3d array.